# Does wxWidgets is still more native than GTK+

Tags: gtk, wxwidgets

It is known that wxWidgets uses native APIs for a native look.
This seems not to be the case for GTK+.
Is this still the case or something have changed?
Why GTK+ cannot use the native API in Windows?

My understanding is that [GTK+](https://www.gtk.org/) is just a program while [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/about/) is a group of programs (one for each OS). While GTK+ uses libraries like GObject to achieve portability, wxWidgets was built from scratch in each specific platform. Is this correct?

Please, provide detail like what API is using GTK+ in Windows and what API is using wxWidgets instead.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wxWidgets uses native Win32 API for drawing and for UI, i.e. various controls in wxWidgets are the native Windows Shell controls when running under Windows.

GTK+ still uses some low-level Win32 API to be able to run under Windows at all, but it uses its own controls which it draws itself using its own drawing library too.

Both GTK+ and wxWidgets are libraries and not programs and both contain platform-independent and platform-specific code, although wxWidgets has much more (proportionally speaking) of the latter than GTK+.